# model.predict() in Keras not working properly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, classification

I am working with a data set to see whether a review of a movie is positive(1) or negative(0) and I completed my model's training and when I tried to predict the output of a review it went like this

[image]

I dont know what to do and what that "red color" highlighted line means; and my code to train and return output is

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(80000, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = "relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss= "binary_crossentropy", metrics  = ["accuracy"])
x_val = train_data[:10000]
x_train = train_data[10000:]
y_val = train_labels[:10000]
y_train = train_labels[10000:]
fitmodel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 40, batch_size=512, verbose=1)
results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_labels)
print(results)
print("Review:")
print(decode_review(train_data[1])) 
#decode_review is just a function that prints text form of review because originally it is in the for 
#of numbers to train our neural network
print("Actual Classification:")
print(train_labels[1])
print("Predection")
out = model.predict_classes([train_data[1]])
print(out)
```

and the output must be a (single) sigmoid neuron because the last layer of the network is the following (which is a single neuron) if observed the code above you may already see this line

```
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid"))
```

but if you observe the photo you may already observe that the output is a huge array of digits(0, 1)....[ **BUT I WANT TO GET OUTPUT AS 0 OR 1 AND I THINK THAT RED HIGHLIGHTED LINE IN PHOTO MEANS SOMETHING CAN ANYONE EXPLAIN WHATS WRONG WITH MY CODE**]

incase you want to observe and run my code. All my code will be available [here](https://github.com/Decoding-The-Universe/stackoverflow)
for further clarification please comment down. **THANKS**

Comment: Use ```model.predict([train_data[1]])```.

Comment: It is just a deprecation message, look two lines above the red message. No need to yell abou it.

Comment: @yudhiesh I tried that but that too gave same output but in the form of decimals for eg. if predict_classes() gives 0 predict() gives a small value instead of 0 like 0.0003 and same goes for 1 it outputs 0.934... instead of 1. but finally the results are the same by two methods if we round of the numbers.......

Comment: Yes as @Dr.Snoopy mentions it is a depreciation warning not an error so its not an issue.